# Getting `HTTPS security is compromised` in ms-word addin on IE11

Tags: iframe, ms-word, internet-explorer-11, x-frame-options, clickjacking

As the title states, I'm having issues with displaying my page in an iframe using `x-frame-options: sameorigin`

Looking at possible solutions, I came across `x-frame-options: allow-from url`, which made no difference. All of my resources are also served via https.
When using both `x-frame-options: sameorigin` and `X-Frame-Options: allow-from url`, the sameorigin header is disabled.

Also, documentation on `x-frame-options` found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options):

```
# ALLOW-FROM uri 
This is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers. Don't use it. In 
supporting legacy browsers, a page can be displayed in a frame only on the specified origin 
uri. Note that in the legacy Firefox implementation this still suffered from the same problem 
as SAMEORIGIN did — it doesn't check the frame ancestors to see if they are in the same origin.
The Content-Security-Policy HTTP header has a frame-ancestors directive which you can use 
instead.
```

I currently have the abovementioned `frame-ancestors` implemeted for other browsers' support, eg. Chrome, Safari, or Firefox, which is however unsupported by IE11. This is a security layer that I don't want to remove to avoid clickjacking.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you please inform us, where you are implementing those response headers? did you only try with the `x-frame-options: sameorigin`? Does that worked with the IE browser? Please try to check whether any of the resource files like JS, CSS or any other file is using the HTTP protocol or not. It may cause this error.

Comment: I managed to find a solution for this which worked for IE11 and didn't affect the other browsers. These headers are added server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the question, I found that when appending another `x-frame-options` header, the `sameorigin` was disabled.

So I modified the header slightly and found the following to work perfectly for IE11 and did not affect the other browsers:

```
res.set("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN, ALLOW-FROM url");
```